# Synchronize two local sql databases

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I want to synchronize two SQL local databases.I don't know how to do this please inform me step by step and which tool is used for synchronize the databases.

Comment: You're more likely to get helpful answers if you show that you have attempted / done a reasonable amount of research yourself. Have you tried what any of the online resources say? Such as [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd918848(v=sql.110).aspx)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that no one could help you with such less information. But you could start reading and learning: [SQL Replication MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx)